# ActionBar tabs and multi-fragment layout with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I have an application that uses `ActionBar` tabs for navigation. With these tabs I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a `ViewPager` in the layout.

I have configured these in my application's main `Activity`. In there I add a page change listener for the `ViewPager` and change tabs regarding to position. I also do it the other way around when a tab is pressed. This is all fine.

Then I have the contents I have in the tabs. Both of them extend `Fragment` class. The first one has to change the layout according to the device. On landscape tablets (`layout-sw600dp-land`) I have a layout with two fragments and other devices will have only one fragment. This is done by two layout files in appropiate folders.

On these smaler devices, the second fragment is used as a dialog.

I'm not really sure how to implement this all. The first fragment contains a ListView with all kind of tasks. When one of those is clicked, an editing window should appear to the right fragment. On small devices, the fragment doesn't exist so it needs to be started as an Activity. Currently this editing window is a `FragmentActivity`.

How do I do this? I'm not sure if it's really harder, but I think the Fragment inside Fragment confuses me.

Comment: You have a `ViewPager` with two pages where the first fragment will need to show either one or two fragments depending on some layout configuration?

Comment: That's right. Tablets in landscape mode need to show two fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not really sure how to implement this all.

This shouldn't be too hard. It's conceptually as the multi pane project but instead of juggling between activities using appropriate fragments you'll work with nested fragments.

You'll have a master/wrapper fragment in the `ViewPager` which will represent the adaptive page which will have either one or two nested fragment depending on the current configuration(those fragments will need to be attached at runtime(a limitation of the nested fragments)). Knowing the current configuration you also need to handle the selection/click/trigger event appropriately either by starting a new activity(this is what I understood from your question, but you're a little ambiguous here) or setting up the details fragment in the same wrapper fragment.

I've made a small sample, related to your problem, that you can find [here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/fragment/MultiPageChange.java). I hope is what you want, of course keep in mind that is something basic.

Comment: I tried something similar earlier (and this one now). The problem is, that nothing is shown in the multipane fragment. I tried adding System.out.printlns for debugging in the class and none of the methods seem to be called. I'm talking of the class that you named `MultiPageHandleFragment`. The other Fragment is shown correctly. I have also followed this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html. I have two layouts. One shows only one Fragment and the second one shows two fragments. Here's some of my code. http://pastebin.com/ncCLjhYs http://pastebin.com/d67WebXg

Comment: Pastebin seems to have messed up with the indentations.

Comment: @MikkoP The code you posted would not work(does `activity_main_view` have both fragment embedded in the layout(which shouldn't work)?). My approach(which does work) is to have the `MultiPageHandleFragment`(MainView in your code) which inflates a layout based on configuration(having only place holder containers not the fragments themselves!) and based on the inflated layout add the inner fragment as nested fragments(which from what I've seen you're not doing). Try actually running my sample code in an emulator to see it in action, maybe I'm not understanding what you want.

Comment: I tried your application and it is what I want. I fixed some problems in my version and now it works better. Now I have the two fragments on the one tab. I still have to work with this list which is equivalent to your `NavigationFragment`. http://pastebin.com/E4xT43fV

Comment: @MikkoP Look at the NavigationFragment. In your code in the list's `OnItemClickListener` you simply start a new Activity to do the edit no matter what layout you're in. You need to handle the multi pane situation: if you're in a layout with the two fragments then update the editing window fragment with the new item to be edited otherwise start the EditMuteTask activity. I delegated this to the `MultiPageHandleFragment` to avoid tying both nested fragments together.

Comment: Will this work if i want to use 5 pages with 2 nested fragment(multi-pane layout) ? @Luksprog

Comment: @Luksprog Yea it works, i implemented it and did :-)

Answer (score 0):

First Convert That Editing Window from Activity to Fragment.

Desing the different page for tab and mobile like:
1. For Tab - Design the page like listview in left side and framelayout at right to listview
2. For device - Listview in one page and create another activity for editing window

Now you have two different page for same activity by using layout folder right.

Now you need to Check whether The framlayout is null or not. If null, then your app running in phone so you can trigger next activity which have editing window when you click the list item. If not null , then you have framelayout in right side of listview so just attach the editing fragment into framelayout.